# associate one record to another via rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations, models

I'm new to RoR and I'm practicing Models and associations.

I've created some users and orders via rails console using:

```
order = Order.create(body: "i'm a new order")
user = User.create(name: "Borja")
```

I would like to know how to assign a post with certain id to an user with certain id (for example, post(2) belongs to user(1) ), so I can check the methods of this relation using rails console.

Thank you!

models/user.rb >

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
end
```

models/post.rb >

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Comment: `user.posts.create()` or `Post.create(user_id: user.id)` where `user` can be `user = User.first`

Answer (score 1):

You named the class `Order` it intentionally or it's a mistake?

Either you need to change file name to `order.rb` or you need to change model name to `Post`

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
 end
```

Create post in user scope

```
user = User.find(1)
user.posts.create(body: "some text") # user id will be passed automatically

# or

user = User.find(1)
Post.create(user_id: user.id, body: "some text")
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, you want to find a user or create a user (if one doesn't exist).
- Then you want to find or create a post (if it doesn't exist)
- Then you want to call the right method to associate the user with the post.

Think of the [methods that `User` class gains when a `has_many` association is declared](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) inside it.

The above isn't the optimal way to associate a user to a post but it is the bare minimum and will get you thinking about associations work.

PS: Make sure you format your questions correctly. This way more people will be motivated to answer.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look :)